# Replacing strings line by line

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a text file testfile.txt, the file contents (input) look like the following:

```
Msg "how are you"
Msg "Subtraction is", 10-9
```

Output should look like the following,

```
Msg("how are you")
Msg("Subtraction is", 10-9)
```

I opened the file as following,

```
fileopening = open('testfile.txt', 'r')
fileopening.readline()

for line in fileopening:
   print line.replace(' "', '(')
for line in fileopening:
   print line.replace('"', ')')
```

But the code above actually changes the previously converted space and quote. How can this be accomplished to make it look like the desired output shown above? I want to take Msg as a single line and wrap the Msg with ( ) and go to the next line.

**My new output looked like this:**

```
Msg( "hello"
)

()
Msg( "dfsdkbfsd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `replace`, you could take advantage of the fact that the parentheses are always inserted at the 4th position and the last position:

```
with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as fileopening:
    next(fileopening)
    for line in fileopening:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print('{}({})'.format(line[:3], line[4:]))
```

By the way, since you are using Python3, note that `print` is a function and therefore its argument **must** be surrounded by parentheses. Using `print` without parentheses raises `SyntaxErrors`.

Comment: `line[4:-1]` looks odd, why not `line[4:]`?

Comment: The last character in `line` is an end-of-line character.

Comment: @unutbu My new output looks a little weird.

Comment: You are probably a Windows user. Then you need to use `line[4:].rstrip()` instead of `line[4:-1]`, because otherwise the trailing `\r` (carriage return) is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem would be as follows:

```
with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        newline = line.replace(' "', '("')
        newline = newline.replace('\n', ')\n')
        print newline
```

This wouldn't presume that every line starts with Msg.

Comment: `Msg "Are", "you", "sure?"`