# Replace one part of strings based on its another part

Tags: python

I have series of strings given through a text file,

strings.txt:

```
printing "This is not easy!"
John Roberts and Judiciary
printing "valid hello"      $ printing "comment" 
printing "abc",
```

These contents will be the input. The output MUST look like the following,

```
printing("This is not easy!")
John Roberts and Judiciary
printing("valid hello")      $ printing "comment" 
printing ("abc", shell=" ")
```

Here, whenever we see printing, it should add ( ) in both ends. But if the printing comes after $ it should not put ( ). It should be left alone. If the printing have a comma at the end, then the printing should include a comma and after that it should have shell=" " .

Thank fully I used this: [Replacing strings line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880895/replacing-strings-line-by-line)

```
def main():
    with open('string.txt', 'r') as fileopening:
        next(fileopening)
        for line in fileopening:
            if 'printing' in line:
                print '{}({})'.format(line[:9], line[9:])
```

But it only displays:

```
printing("This is not easy!")
John Roberts and Judiciary
printing("valid hello")      $ printing("comment")
```

How can it be accomplished?

Comment: `printing "valid hello" $ printing "comment" ` are those on the same line ?. I think you gonna have to use regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just a few logic. This would work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def main():
    with open('C:\\Temp\\001.txt', 'r') as fileopening, \
    open('C:\\Temp\\002.txt', 'w') as fileTarget:
        for line in fileopening:
            if 'printing' in line and '$' not in line:
                lineInfo = line.split('"')
                lineInfo[0] += '("'
                if line.endswith(','):
                    lineInfo[-2] += '", '
                    lineInfo[-1] = 'shell=" ")'
                else:
                    lineInfo[-2] += '")'
                line = ''.join(lineInfo)

            elif 'printing' in line and '$' in line:
                lineInfo = line.split('"')
                lineInfo[0] += '("'
                lineInfo[1] += '")'
                lineInfo[-2] = '"'+lineInfo[-2]+'"'
                line = ''.join(lineInfo)    
            fileTarget.write(line)

main()
```

Comment: worked great. But what if it is 'print' instead of 'printing' . How would the line index change?

Comment: @Gworld Try replace 'printing' with 'print' in the code.